# jQuery closest function

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox

Alright I know that the .closest() have been discussed before, but I have been searching, and I still can't get it working.

The situation is this. I have a table with some checkboxes and labels. Now when a checkbox is checked I want a div to appear, and disappear when unchecked. Keep in mind that this is dynamic PHP code.

I have got it working this far, but the current issue is that all the message divs appear instead of just the appropriate one.

```
$('[name^="check"]').click(function() {
    $(".message").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Now the checkboxes have names such as check1, check2 and check3. A matter of how many that is generated.

I have tried to play around with different this(), parent() and closest() functions in my attempt to select just one of the divs, but I can't get it working.

Thank you for your attention.

Edit:

The HTML that is rendered look somewhat like this (simplified)

```
<div style="float: left;">
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="check1" value="1"><label for="check1">Label for check1</label></div>
<div class="message" style="display: none; ">FOO</div>

<div style="float: left;">
<input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="check2" value="2"><label for="check2">Label for check2</label></div>
<div class="message" style="display: none; ">FOO</div>
```

Comment: `closest()`, `parent()` and all variations will only work it the check box is inside the `div`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you, with your provided markup.

```
$('[name^="check"]').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next(".message").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

*Side node:* you could improve your selector performance by using `input[name^="check"]` so jQuery does not need to iterate through *all* elements.

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/5BpZm/1/).**

Comment: @Henrik, You should still delegate (http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) rather then `click` in this kind of scenario

Answer (score 1):

`closest()`, `parent()` and all variations will only work it the check box is inside the div.

```
$('[name^="check"]').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next(".message").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

With that said, you should avoid mass adding of event handlers. Better to use [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
$('#table_id').delegate('[name^="check"]', function() { ... });
```

This approach only adds **one** event listener, rather than on for each checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[name^="check"]').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().children("div.message").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Assuming your div and your checkbox have the same parent.